# increase the limit of request for form-data in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express and sending request as **FORM-DATA**

ERROR -

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
at readStream (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
at getRawBody (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
at read (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
at jsonParser (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:134:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at query (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (e:\MindfulSAS\myGit\hereiam-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
```

is their any way to increase the limit of request for form-data ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think below may help you

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Comment: And how it can be fixed for specific route. For instance for '/admin' route only?

Answer (score 0):

Use Body Parser NPM : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: '50mb',
  parameterLimit: 100000
  }))

 app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '50mb',
  parameterLimit: 100000
 }))
```